# Django easy-thumbnails plugin makes darker images

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, django-cms, easy-thumbnails

I get this behavior only while using easy_thumbnails. If the image is not processed through easy_thumbnails it works well.
When cropping (through easy_thumbnails) images get darker and with different hue (more green). Could it be something with the colorspace through the process?

Did anyone have a similar issue?
Thanks

Comment: OK, I figured it out. It was a problem with images which were not sRGB. When converted everything works fine.